# Chrome Binary Not Found on AWS Lambda Using Serverless and chrome-aws-lambda Node package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, aws-lambda, serverless

I have created a simple application that accepts a URL and converts it to a PDF. It stores the resultant PDF in an S3 bucket and returns the URL of the PDF. It uses Chrome (running headless) to convert the URL to a PDF. I used the serverless framework, AWS Lambda, and the chrome-aws-lambda npm package. When I execute this setup locally using serverless it all works great. I can use postman to make a request with a URL and it returns the URL of the resultant PDF. When I deploy this setup to AWS Lambda, it returns a 502 internal server error response. When I look at the AWS logs for my application I see the following:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//../bin/chromium.br'",
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": -2,
    "syscall": "open",
    "path": "//../bin/chromium.br",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//../bin/chromium.br'"
    ]
}
```

Here is the main handler for the application:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import middy from 'middy'
import chromium from 'chrome-aws-lambda'
import {
  cors,
  doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop,
  httpHeaderNormalizer,
  httpErrorHandler
} from 'middy/middlewares'

const handler = async (event) => {
  // Request body is passed in as a JSON encoded string in 'event.body'
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body)

  const executablePath = event.isOffline
    ? './node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-706915/chrome-linux/chrome'
    : await chromium.executablePath

  const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: executablePath,
    headless: true
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto(data.url, {
    waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'load', 'domcontentloaded']
  })

  const pdfStream = await page.pdf()

  var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: 'bucketname',
      Body: pdfStream,
      Key: `${Date.now()}-result.pdf`,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }
  })

  var promise = upload.promise()

  return promise.then(
    function (data) {
      console.log(data.Location)
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: data.Location
      }
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log('Error', err)
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: err
      }
    }
  )
}

export const generate = middy(handler)
  .use(httpHeaderNormalizer())
  .use(cors())
  .use(doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop())
  .use(httpErrorHandler())
```

Here is the serverless framework configuration file:

```
service: print-pdf

package:
  individually: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-2
  stage: prod

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle # Package our functions with Webpack
  - serverless-offline

# Create our resources with separate CloudFormation templates
resources:
  # API Gateway Errors
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-errors.yml)}
  # S3
  - ${file(resources/s3-bucket.yml)}

# 'iamRoleStatements' defines the permission policy for the Lambda function.
# In this case Lambda functions are granted with permissions to access S3.
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - s3:GetObject
      - s3:PutObject
    Resource: "arn:aws:s3:us-east-2:*:*"

functions:
  give-me-the-pdf:
    handler: handler.generate
    events:
      - http:
          path: pdf
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "print-pdf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "author": "Dean Andreakis <dean@deanware.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "serverless-bundle test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^1.20.4",
    "middy": "^0.28.4",
    "puppeteer-core": "^1.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.597.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "serverless": ">=1.48.1",
    "serverless-bundle": "^1.2.5",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

Why is Chrome not found when deployed to AWS versus running locally?

Comment: It's likely caused by the way serverless packages applications. Have you tried using [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) and configuring `chrome-aws-lamdba` as an external? There's a similar issue [here](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/67).

Comment: jpetty Your suggestion to use serverless-webpack etc. was what ultimately resolved my issues. If you could turn this into an answer I would gladly award you the bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) and configure `chrome-aws-lamdba` as an external.

There's a similar issue [here](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/67).

Add this to your webpack config:

```
externals: ['aws-sdk', 'chrome-aws-lambda']
```

Comment: how to handle the same error using `SAM` (not _serverless framework_). Any help there?

Comment: What if the project is not using `serverless-webpack`?

Answer (score 0):

`serverless-bundle` only includes the JS code that you use in your handler and strips everything else to minimize your bundle. That means the chrome binaries are excluded.

To include those binaries, add the following to your `serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
  bundle:
    copyFiles:
      - from: 'node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/*'
        to: './'
```

Comment: It seems to have helped but now I am getting the following error:

"Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn ./ EACCES"

Comment: Hi Dean, can you check if the bundle copy all the required files.  There are also public layers with the required modules for running chrome on lambda ( https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer ), you can use one of that or check the steps to create your own.

Comment: OK I used the public layer for chrome-aws-lambda but I still get "Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn /opt/nodejs/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium.br EACCES"

Comment: Hi Dean, I check my lambda for printing and I use `puppeteer` for launching chrome like this... 

https://gist.github.com/pepoviola/3316771686bd1e7d43c6ddeb068d2e45

Comment: how do I include using SAM?